FLINK deletes data when inserting into ORACLE table
I am inserting data from flink to oracle table (using user FLINK) and get error

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01031: insufficient
privileges.

I checked the history in the v$sql table and discovered that FLINK performed a number of DELETE statements like this:
DELETE FROM FLINK.AGG_ACCT_STATEMENT_FL WHERE DAYID = :1 AND ENTRY_ID = :2 AND TRANS_TYPE = :3

I checked the permissions of user FLINK again, then checked and found out the reason is that FLINK does not have DELETE permission.
I am using Ververica's flink 1.19.0
Why does FLINK need DELETE permission when insert data to oracle and which operation requires DELETE permission? I am worried about database fragmentation when performing too many delete operations.

Do not be concerned about fragmentation caused by deletes. Space in blocks can be reused when the free space in the block passes a certain threshhold, and as blocks are reformatted in their entirety each time, it does not fragment space within the block, ever. Where we have concern about fragmentation is with extent deallocation (move, truncate, drop) and reuse, but that's at the tablespace (not table) level, none of which is caused by deletes.
